# Raspberry PI IP address

Tags: raspberry-pi

I have a Raspberry PI and a Wi-Pi wireless dongle.

I want to connect the PI to the computer using Remote Desktop Connection via wireless.

But I'm not sure how to get the IP of the Raspberry (without having access to the router), that I need to connect to it.

Now I get into router's page and see what IP it assigned to the pi, and use it to connect

But my goal is to be able to use it on the "field", using the phone's "internet sharing" option, to connect the PI and laptop to it, and then connect to pi from the laptop.

How can I get the IP address that the phone gave to the PI?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could make your Raspberry Pi speak its IP-address, like described [here](http://darrenjw2.wordpress.com/2012/11/28/getting-a-headless-raspberry-pi-to-speak-its/).

First, install the espeak package:

```
$ sudo apt-get install espeak
```

Then, create a init script:

```
$ sudo vi /etc/init.d/sayIPbs
```

Paste the following content into it:

```
#! /bin/sh
# /etc/init.d/sayIPbs
## Some things that run always
# Carry out specific functions when asked to by the system
case "$1" in  start)
    echo "Starting script sayIPbs "
    sleep 5
    public=`curl ifconfig.me`
    private=`hostname -I`
    string="public address is $public and private address is $private"
    echo $string | espeak -s 120 -v en-uk
    sleep 2
    echo $string | espeak -s 120 -v en-uk
    ;;  stop)    
echo "Stopping script sayIPbs"
    ;;  *)
    echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/sayIPbs {start|stop}"
    exit 1
    ;;esac
exit 0
```

Finally, issue these commands:

```
$ cd /etc/init.d
$ sudo chmod a+x sayIPbs
$ sudo update-rc.d -f sayIPbs defaults
$ sudo reboot
```

Plug in some headphones and listen to the ip address which will be read out at the end of the boot process.

Comment: This worked for me. Since I'm only interested in my Pi's private IP4 address, I changed the string to `hostname -I | sed -e 's/ .*//' -e 's/\./ dot /g'`.

Answer (score 3):

You should configure your raspy to have always the same ip address. Try to edit your interfaces.man file with nano or cat command with your own parameters as shown below. Remember to reboot after editing:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ cat /etc/network/interfaces.man 
auto lo

    iface lo inet loopback
    iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.69
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.1.1


    auto wlan0
    allow-hotplug wlan0
    iface wlan0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.67
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.1.1
    wpa-passphrase password
    wpa-ssid myssid
```

Answer (score 2):

I found that I can use [nmap](http://nmap.org/) to "scan" the network for connected devices, and it will give me a list of devices and their assigned IP.

And since there's max 3 devices connected, the list is short and easy to read.

```
nmap -sP 192.168.1.1/24
```

Answer (score 2):

Using just a button and an LED, I have written a script that gets the IP address of the Raspberry pi, and then blinks the LED repeatedly to show the IP address of the Raspberry Pi. I just count the blinks, note them down on paper, and then I have the IP address. It seems silly, but works with Just 2 I/O pins.

Answer (score 2):

Use `static IP` on you pi by editing on `/etc/network/interfaces`. but, on the other way, you can also install `network scanner` on your phone.

Answer (score 1):

Bit late answer, but I had similar issue intitially.   Solved my problem in the following way:

- Use the Unix terminal commands to identify the IP and the MAC address of wi-fi or ethernet port (ifconfig)
- set up your router to always allocate a address to these respective network connections.  use range outside what would be automatically generated with DHCP

Whenever you connect that raspberry Pi to your network   it will automatically be allocated that address.  I also put sticker on the pi with the mac and IP address.   Especially useful if you are running it without screen and keyboard.